# SQL GROUP BY and differences on same field (for MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Hi I have the following style of table under MS Access: (I didn't make the table and cant change it)

```
Date_r          |  Id_Person |Points |Position
25/05/2015    |  120       | 2000  | 1 
25/05/2015    |  230       | 1500  | 2 
25/05/2015    |  100       |  500  | 3 
21/12/2015    |  120       | 2200  | 1 
21/12/2015    |  230       | 2000  | 4 
21/12/2015    |  100       |  200  | 20
```

what I am trying to do is to get a list of players (identified by Id_Person) ordered by the points difference between 2 dates.
So for example if I pick date1=25/05/2015 and date2=21/12/2015 I would get:
Id_Person |Points_Diff
  230                  | 500  
  120            | 200   
  100            |-300

I think I need to make something like

```
SELECT Id_Person , MAX(Points)-MIN(Points)
FROM Table
WHERE date_r = #25/05/2015# or date_r = #21/12/2015#
GROUP BY Id_Person
ORDER BY MAX(Points)-MIN(Points) DESC
```

But my problem is that i don't really want to order by (MAX(Points)-MIN(Points)) but rather by (points at date2 - points at date1) which can be different because points can decrease with the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `first` and `last`  However, this can sometimes produce strange results, so I think that conditional aggregation is best:

```
SELECT Id_Person,
       (MAX(IIF(date_r = #25/05/2015#, Points, 0)) -
        MIN(IIF(date_r = #21/05/2015#, Points, 0))
       ) as PointsDiff
FROM Table
WHERE date_r IN (#25/05/2015#,  #21/12/2015#)
GROUP BY Id_Person
ORDER BY (MAX(IIF(date_r = #25/05/2015#, Points, 0)) -
          MIN(IIF(date_r = #21/05/2015#, Points, 0))
         ) DESC;
```

Because you have two dates, this is more easily written as:

```
SELECT Id_Person,
       SUM(IIF(date_r = #25/05/2015#, Points, -Points)) as PointsDiff
FROM Table
WHERE date_r IN (#25/05/2015#,  #21/12/2015#)
GROUP BY Id_Person
ORDER BY SUM(IIF(date_r = #25/05/2015#, Points, -Points)) DESC;
```

Comment: Except that you should never use the dd/mm/yyyy format as it will fail when dd can be read as a month, thus: `WHERE date_r IN (#2015/05/25#,  #2015/12/21#)`

Comment: @Gustav . . . I do agree.  I was just leaving the format the way the OP had presented it.